# copy object in javascript

Tags: javascript, copy

I want to copy object from "xwalk.utils.converter" to "xwalk.converter"
the converter has these functions.
Is it available copy of object? otherwise alias?

> xwalk.utils.converter.toArray
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toBoolean
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toByte
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toDictionary
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toDouble
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toEnum
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toFunction
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toLong
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toLongLong
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toOctet
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toPlatformObject
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toShort
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toUnsignedLong
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toUnsignedLongLong
>
> xwalk.utils.converter.toUnsignedShort

Comment: you can use a deep extend/copy, see http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#deep_extend

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, which recursively copies the elements:

```
function copy(src) {
    var destination = {};
    for (var index in src) {
        if (typeof src[index] === "object") {
            destination[index] = copy(src[index]);
        } else if (Array.isArray(src[index])) {
            destination[index] = [];
            for (var arrIndex in src[index]) {
                if ((typeof src[index][arrIndex] === "object") || (Array.isArray(src[index][arrIndex]))) {
                    destination[index][arrIndex] = copy(src[index][arrIndex]);
                } else {
                    destination[index][arrIndex] = src[index];
                }
            }
        } else {
            destination[index] = src[index];
        }
    }
    return destination;
}
```

Usage:

```
xwalk.converter = xwalk.utils.converter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
var copy = function(from, to) {
  for (var prop in from) {
    if (from.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      to[prop] = from[prop];
    }
  }
};

copy(xwalk.utils.converter,xwalk.converter);
```

Comment: thnx but it doesn't work... because xwalk is loaded like this ..
var xwalk_loader = require('node-xwalk');
xwalk_loader.extension_paths.push('/usr/lib/extensions-crosswalk/');
var xwalk = xwalk_loader.require('utils');

Comment: It's not a js object?